# How do I check if a user has the 'manage_options' capability in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if the current user can manage options. I'm using the following code:

```
if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    add_filter('comments_array', 'myFunctionCall');
}
```

But it produces this error (in WordPress 2.9.2, latest):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function wp_get_current_user() in
>   /Users/******/Sites/*****.com/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 969

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code and works fine in my site (using WP 2.9.2 too).

Check that the function is defined in the `pluggable.php` file inside `/wp-includes`.

In my WP installation I've got the function defined from **line 69 to 76**:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_get_current_user') ) :
/**
 * Retrieve the current user object.
 *
 * @since 2.0.3
 *
 * @return WP_User Current user WP_User object
 */
function wp_get_current_user() {
    global $current_user;

    get_currentuserinfo();

    return $current_user;
}
endif;
```

Comment: Yeah, I finally figured out that I need to call `get_currentuserinfo()` before checking for capabilities. Novice mistake! Thanks!